# Get Date in Consistent Format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

I am having a function which return the date based on some condition (last 30 day).

```js
const start = new Date();
start.setTime(start.getTime() - 3600 * 1000 * 24 * 30);
const startTime = start.toLocaleString().split(",")[0];
console.log(startTime)
```

In Mac OS,I am getting the output in dd/mm/yyyy format (which is the desired format).

But in Windows , I am getting the output in mm/dd/yyyy. How can I make it consistent irespective of platform. Desired format is dd/mm/yyy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `toLocaleDateString` with 'en-GB'

```js
const start = new Date();
start.setDate(start.getDate() - 30)
const startTime = start.toLocaleDateString('en-GB');
console.log(startTime)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [toLocaleDateString with locale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString#using_locales)

The en-GB locale seems what you want here

I made a more useful and self-describing function

```js
const ddmmyyyy = (d, offset) => {
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (3600 * 1000 * 24 * offset))
  return d.toLocaleDateString('en-GB')
};

console.log(
  ddmmyyyy(new Date(), -30)
)
```

Comment: 'en-GB' is a language, not a locale. It baffles me why the authors of ECMA-402 specified a parameter value that is a BCP47 language code but managed to misname it "locale". Even the introduction says "*\[ECMA-402\] provides key language sensitive functionality…*". :-)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function SetShortDateTime(d) {
  const monthList = [
    "01",
    "02",
    "03",
    "04",
    "05",
    "06",
    "07",
    "08",
    "09",
    "10",
    "11",
    "12"
  ];


  const yr = d.getFullYear();
  const mnt = monthList[d.getMonth()];
  const day = d.getDate() < 10 ? "0" + d.getDate() : d.getDate();

  return [day, mnt, yr].join("/");
}

console.log(SetShortDateTime(new Date(2021,11,9,10)))
```

Comment: I fixed your padding. But why not use padStart on both day and month? Then just do `mnt = d.getMonth()+1;`

Comment: Or just do what we did. `start.toLocaleDateString('en-GB');` will do all that